# Code related files as a map : What goes where and what is exported onto what

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio on my MacBook, and I'm trying to understand someone else's code, which is probably the hardest thing to do. The code is in the form of a package which has several folders and each folder has different files. Is there a way to look at what classes are getting exported from a file and where are these classes used etc. etc. etc. as some sort of an inter-dependency or a relational map?

I looked at a feature called code map on visual studio but havent been successful in finding out how to use it in my mac version of visual studio